# Correct name of installed applications

Tags: android

I am getting the names for my installed applications with below code and use them to see if any updates for this application is available.

But sometimes an incorrect name (MX Speler instead of MX Player) is being provided, as a result no updates are found.

Is there any better code i can/should use?

```
 {
    final PackageInfo pi = installedInfo != null ? installedInfo : downloadedInfo;

    final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
        try {
                ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(pi ??, 0); //How to set the name of the installed application?
            }   catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
                ai = null;
            }
            final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
            System.out.println("Application name : "+ applicationName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **labels** as it may be different for every language or changed on each update. You should only rely on application's **id** (packageId) as this id stays unchanged for the whole life of the application.

Comment: Hi Marcin, how would i use this in my code?, could you give an example please?

Comment: see my edited code but how do i set the name (pi). Could you please have a look?